# "Template:Template other" is on the top of the page despite the fact I didn't put it there

Tags: mediawiki

[image: The preview]

If it helps, I'm using Miraheze as my host of choice. As you can see from the above, it says `Template: Template other` despite the fact the page source begins with:

```
{{Infobox
|image    = [[File:4004small.png]]
<!-- snip -->

The '''4004''', released in 1971, is the first microprocessor developed by Intel, and is regarded as the first...
```

Nowhere in the source is "Template other" mentioned, the only other templates I use are `{{PAGENAME}}` and `{|` for a table. How should I get rid of that red text at the top?

Answer (score 1):

I note that there should be a rendered [[template:infobox]] on this preview, which is (*apparently*, it may well have been snipped from the right-hand side of the image) missing. I believe [[Template:template other]] is called by [[template:infobox]] or another template that has been snipped off the code (which may well not be a minimal working example) and because it is missing—i.e. probably because the infobox page was imported (probably from Wikipedia or another wiki with complex multi-level templates) without the various other required templates it calls up—, it ends up throwing this onto the page.